# ac phasor voltage between capacitor and inductor higher than source voltage?

Tags: voltage, capacitor, inductor, phasor

I've just learned about phasors and I am very confused about this. Take this circuit as an example:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmCJ9v.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

So by what I've learned, All I would have to do is use the voltage division formula, after computing impedances:

z1 = -j

z2 = j

z3 = 1

Now I combine z3 and z2:

z* = z2 + z3 = 1 + j

And now voltage division:

Vm1 = 10 * (1 + j) / (1 + j - j)

Vm1 = 10 * (1 + j) / (1)

Vm1 = 10 + 10 j

Vm1 =  14.14 (angle 45)

???????

Somehow, the voltage at this location is higher than the source voltage. how could this be?

Is it not a violation of KVL?

Thanks so much for any answer.

Comment: Resonant circuits can have a larger voltage across one component than the other. Just FYI for your circuit you've calculated the impedances incorrectly, either that or your source has the wrong frequency.

Comment: Apparent impedance is sqrt(1^2+(-j1)^2) so series current produces root 2 voltage on each reactive part. Then for large ratios of  X(f)/R=Q = the voltage gain at resonance limited to 100 for 1% accuracy tolerance and R of reactive parts. For parallel, just the inverse, Q=R/X(f)

Comment: @TonyStewartEEsince1975 Thank you, I dont really understand, but it sounds like you know exactly what your'e doing. Do you mean to say that there is something wrong in my calculation? Or something wrong in the interpretation of my results? In either case, how is the fault with KVL dealt with?  Thanks!

Comment: The only fault was your assumption and then say how can this be. It is correct except you did not state ω =1. Now if R changed to 0.1 , V increase inversely from the stored energy being much higher than the loss or (I^2*) X/R ratio

Comment: You are seeing the effect of stored energy. Make that R 10x smaller, and the Volts at L+C rise. Make that R 100X smaller, and the Volts rise yet again. Imagine what happens inside a quartz-crystal-resonator, with Q of a million.

Comment: Imagine you're pumping a swing in a play park. You move your body only (say) 100mm with respect to the swing, but after many cycles, the swing's oscillation has built up to metres. That's an output amplitude much bigger than the pumping amplitude. It works because it's a low loss resonator, though in this case it's exchanging energy between height and speed, rather than between voltage and current. Increase the losses per cycle, say flood the playpark in mollasses, and the amplification effect (the Q) would be less.

Answer (score 1):

> Somehow, the voltage at this location is higher than the source
>   voltage. how could this be?

If you approach resonance in a series tuned circuit, the capacitive and inductive reactances are cancelling each other out. At resonance XL and XC together produce 0 ohms so, the current that flows is due only to V/R.

Clearly, at all other frequencies (higher or lower than resonance) the current is lower.

At resonance this high current flows through both L and C and you get voltage magnification - more current flows through C (due to L being present) than would flow through C if it were connected directly across the AC supply voltage.

Think of a mechanical equivalent.

[image]

Imagine you had a mass of 1 kg suspended on a spring. You held one end of the spring (in the picture above that would be the solid line at the top) and gently moved that point up and down. If you did this much too quickly the mass would barely move (due to inertia). If you did it too slowly the mass would "follow" your hand movement.

If you did it at the goldilocks frequency the mass would start to move up and down and would progressively move up and down with a larger amplitude until it hits your hand or the spring breaks.

You would find that you need very little hand movement (at resonance) to produce a large undulation in the mass.

Answer (score 0):

When applying KVL to AC circuits you have to use the complex (phasor) voltage.

In this case the voltage across VM1 is 10+10j volts. The voltage across the capacitor is -10j volts. These add up to 10 volts, so there is no contradiction.

You could also calculate the RMS voltage at a particular instant; you will find that it adds up to the voltage of the source at that instant. This follows the KVL law for DC.

The mistake you are making is thinking that the RMS voltages of sine waves add up when you add the sine waves together. They do not. Imagine a 10V sine wave and another 10V sine wave with opposite phase - when you add them, you get 0V, not 20V.